# how to update/install libxml to xampp

Tags: php, xml, dom, xampp, libxml2

I am trying to create a google map with multiple markers. But I came across this code

```
$doc = domxml_new_doc("1.0");
$node = $doc->create_element("markers");
$parnode = $doc->append_child($node);
```

and I am getting this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function domxml_new_doc() in  C:\xampp\htdocs\dlti\phpscriptmap.php on line 5

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::create_element() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dlti\phpscriptmap.php on line 6

Fatal error: Call to undefined method DOMDocument::append_child() in C:\xampp\htdocs\dlti\phpscriptmap.php on line 7

I check my php and my DOM/XML is enabled and my libxml version is 2.7.8. Is my libxml oudated? I have downloaded libxml2-2.4.14.tar.gz but I don't know how to install the library to my php/xampp.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`domxml_new_doc();` is a function from the DOMXML extension in PHP 4. This extension was replaced by [ext/dom](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php) in PHP 5. The methods are more complete and written in camel case.

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$markers = $dom->appendChild(
  $dom->createElement('markers')
);
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked, I edited my question, it turns out domxml is not the only problem. Could you please take a look at it again?